# Reading Parse Local Datastore from device?

Tags: parse-platform

I am currently having issues with trying to Pin Objects to my local data store.  When I print out the Object I see that localId is always null.  Is there some way to reveal the data that is currently in local datastore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it will always print null from what the devs have mentioned.  Always reference their main objectId